# How to to write cypress locator for dynamic input field

Tags: cypress, relative-locators

[image]

How to write locator for this highlighted input field element when ID and Class attribute are dynamic?

Also for this button

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Course name" text is a notable feature of that block of HTML. Select it and use traversal commands to get to the `<input>`

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Course name')
  .next()
  .find('input')
```

Alternatively, the placeholder text could be used (but it seems a bit generic)

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Enter"]')
```

---

For the `<button>` a similar tactic

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Add new course')
  .prev('button')
  .click()
```

Comment: one more help..can you also suggest locator for the button that has dynamic values. I added new screenshot.

Comment: If you want to use the text on the button, that one should be easier - `cy.contains('button', 'Text on the button')`.

Comment: No, it does not have text. it has + icon

Comment: Similar to `<input>`, only use `.prev()`.